# X-Axis Mirror mirrors the bones, but they appear on the same side

Tags: modeling, bones, mirror

So, my problem is this: I started building an armature for a character to do a walk cycle with Blender. Now with X-Axis Mirror ticked, the bones are mirrored but they appear on the same side of the mesh. Here's a picture of the problem:

[image]

So, I tried extruding the shoulder bone with Shift + E, and this is how it turned out. Blender automatically names these bones as _L and _R, why are they mirrored on the same side?

Comment: They are mirrored along -X/+X (in global coordinates). Blender handles bones mirroring along -X/+X only. So the problem is your character is rotated along Y axis. You should rotate your character 90° and preferably apply rotation on it (Ctrl+A then 'rotation'). More globally, rig with no rotation (either armature or obj) this is simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more complete indication (than the comments):

Blender's convention for armature is mirroring along -X / +X axis.

- -X is the right part of the character (on screen on the left when looking in front view)
- +X is the left part (same principle)

To avoid complexity, it is good to rig your character using the **same** orientation and scale for both the armature and your character. And **much preferably** no rotation and no scale.

[image]